# Sorting list based on dictionary keys in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

Is there a short way to sort a list based on the order of another dictionary keys?

suppose I have:

```
lst = ['b', 'c', 'a']
dic = { 'a': "hello" , 'b': "bar" , 'c': "foo" }
```

I want to sort the list to be `['a','b','c']` based on the order of dic keys.

Comment: `{item: dic[item] for item in lst}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a lookup of keys versus their insertion order in `dic`. To do so you can write:

```
>>> lst = ['d', 'b', 'c', 'a']
>>> dic = {"a": "hello", "b": "bar", "c": "foo"}
>>> order = {k: i for i, k in enumerate(dic)}
>>> order
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
```

Using this you can write a simple lookup for the `key` argument of `sorted` to rank items based on `order`.

```
>>> sorted(lst, key=order.get)
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

If there are values in `lst` that are not found in `dic` you should call `get` using a lambda so you can provide a default index. You'll have to choose if you want to rank unknown items at the start or end.

Default to the start:

```
>>> lst = ['d', 'b', 'c', 'a']
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda k: order.get(k, -1))
['d', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Default to the end:

```
>>> lst = ['d', 'b', 'c', 'a']
>>> sorted(lst, key=lambda k: order.get(k, len(order)))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```